# Python equivalent to mcrypt_create_iv in PHP

Tags: php, python, encryption

Basically I am converting PHP CodeIgniter's Encryption Method into Python but I stuck while converting PHP's mcrypt_create_iv library into Python.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mcrypt_create_iv()` is just a PHP interface to OS-level pseudo-random generators (it's not even a part of libmcrypt, contrary to what the function name implies).

Python provides such interfaces via the [os module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and what you need is [os.urandom()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom).

For example, if you need to translate `mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)` into Python, you'd need to write `os.urandom(16)`.

---

To clarify a possible confusion:

You may've used `MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM` or `MCRYPT_RAND` in PHP, but there is literally no reason to use either of those instead of `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` - it is just better by all measurable criteria:

- `MCRYPT_RAND` in particular is NOT suitable for cryptographic purposes, or in other words - it is *insecure*.
- `MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM` can and will block until *new* entropy data is available. You don't want blocking in a web application and the myth that `/dev/random` is somehow better than `/dev/urandom` because of blocking has been [debunked](http://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/02/25/safely-generate-random-numbers/).

`MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` is both non-blocking and secure.